# Erlang: Storing data in a record properly and retrieving it?

Tags: erlang, record

I ran the following code with the output

```
Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> rr(record_io).
[memory]     
2> record_io:store(99).
stored: 2
ok
3> record_io:print().
stored: 2
ok
4>
```

What I wanted to know is how to do I properly store a value into a record, obviously the output for `record_io:print().` should have been `99` and not `2`.  Heres the code.

```
-module(record_io).
-export([store/1, print/0]).
-record(memory, {value}).

store(Value) ->
    #memory{ value = Value},
    io:format("stored: ~p~n",[#memory.value]).

print() ->
    io:format("stored: ~p~n",[#memory.value]).
```

I tried this another way and that too didn't work.

```
4> c(record_io).
record_io.erl:6: Warning: a term is constructed, but never used
{ok,record_io}
5> rr(record_io).
[memory]
6> record_io:store(S,10).
* 1: variable 'S' is unbound
7>
```

The code for the modified record_io.

```
-module(record_io).
    -export([store/2, print/1]).
    -record(memory, {value}).

    store(S,Value) ->
        S#memory{ value = Value},
        io:format("stored: ~p~n",[S#memory.value]),
        S.

    print(S) ->
        io:format("stored: ~p~n",[S#memory.value]).
```

**EDIT:** Solution.

The code

```
-module(record_io).
-export([store/1, print/1]).
-record(memory, {value}).

store(Value) ->
   Rec2 = #memory{ value = Value},
   io:format("stored: ~p~n",[Rec2#memory.value]),
   Rec2.

print(S) ->
   io:format("stored: ~p~n",[S#memory.value]).
```

The command line.

```
Rec = record_io:store(99).
record_io:print(Rec).
stored: 99
{memory,99}
stored: 99
ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify records in Erlang. Only creating new ones. see [How do I modify a record in erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715517/how-do-i-modify-a-record-in-erlang)

Comment: Do I use a record on the command line `Rec2 = Rec1#memory{ value = 99}` and pass it into the function call `store(Rec2).`?

Comment: Just return from the "store" function the newly created struct

Comment: I tried that but then the record `S#memory{value = 99}` makes S unbound and I can't pass `S` like `store(S,Value)` in the first place.